# How to get a membership condition for RegionBoundary using RegionMember

Tags: regions

This is my first question on this forum, but by no means my first problem with Mathematica (which I've been using daily for years).

Consider

```
Clear[x, y]
reg = RegionBoundary[ImplicitRegion[0 < x < 2 \[And] 0 < y < -2 x + 4, {x, y}]];
```

In Mathematica 10.3, the expression

```
RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]
```

evaluates to the following logical condition

```
(x | y) \[Element] Reals && ((x == 0 && 
 0 <= y <= 4) || (0 < x < 2 && (y == 0 || y == 4 - 2 x)) || (x == 
  2 && y == 0))
```

which is correct. However, since version 12 (at least) the result is not a symbolic condition anymore, but a RegionMemberFunction expression.

How can one get the predicate above or something equivalent?

Comment: RegionMember gives logical condition for implicit regions, so I thought to try RegionConvert[reg,"Implicit"]. But that doesn't evaluate. Alternatively, first converting to mesh with Chop[RegionConvert[DiscretizeRegion[reg], "Implicit"]] gives the full region, not the boundary.

Comment: `CylindricalDecomposition[0<x<2&&0<y<-2 x+4,{x,y},"Boundary"]//Simplify`

Comment: @chyanog Consider making your comment into an answer

Comment: I don't even get a `RegionMemberFunction` in MMA 12.0, I just get the expression returned unevaluated.

Answer (score 8):

```
cond = CylindricalDecomposition[0 < x < 2 && 0 < y < -2 x + 4, {x, y}, "Boundary"
  ] // Simplify
```

> (x == 0 && y >= 0 && 2 x + y <= 4) || (0 <=  x && ((y == 0 && x <= 2) || (2 x + y == 4 && x < 2)))

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[cond, {x, y}], Frame -> False]
```

> [image]

Comment: chyanog, thank you very much for the answer, especially for bringing attention to CylindricalDecomposition and its topological powers acquired in version 11.2 (which I had forgotten about!).

Comment: @GregosTroianosEducacional It’s my pleasure.